# Augment queried object with another queried object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Trying to combine two result-objects from a mongoose query into one object.
Why is this not working? Any ideas how to make this work?

```
exports.get = function(req, res, err) {
    Project.findOne({
        _id: req.params.id
    }, function(err, project) {
        Client.findOne({
            _id: project.clientId
        }, function(err, client) {
            project.foo = "bar" // works
            project.client = client; // why is this not working?
            res.send(project); // object has property "foo" but no property "client"
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Mongoose documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document-js)** don't allow adding properties. You need to either call the [**`lean()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) method before **`exec()`** since documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain javascript objects.

From the docs:

```
Project.find().lean().exec(function (err, project) {
    project[0] instanceof mongoose.Document // false
});
```

So your code should look like:

```
exports.get = function(req, res, err) {
    Project.findOne({ '_id': req.params.id })
           .lean()
           .exec(function(err, project) {
               Client.findOne({ '_id': project.clientId })
                     .lean()
                     .exec(function(err, client) {
                         project.foo = "bar" // works
                         project.client = client; // works
                         res.send(project); // object has both properties
                     });
           });
}
```

or cast the returned document to a plain JS object:

```
exports.get = function(req, res, err) {
    Project.findOne({
        _id: req.params.id
    }, function(err, project) {
        Client.findOne({
            _id: project.clientId
        }, function(err, client) {
            var obj = project.toObject();
            obj.foo = "bar" // works
            obj.client = client; // works
            res.send(obj); // object has both properties
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Just found out, that the virtuals defined in the project-model are not working anymore this way. One would expect that they are "implemented" into the querries returned object, but that doesnt seem the case. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: I don't know if there is any workaround since as described by the mongoose docs, documents returned from queries with the lean option true are plain javascript objects, not Mongoose Documents. They have no save method, getters/setters or other Mongoose magic applied like virtuals so you might be in a conundrum. You could either create a wrapping object that has two keys which hold the Mongoose docs and send it to the client e.g. `res.send({ "project": project, "client": client })`

Comment: Yep, thats what I had before. Not pretty, but will do. Thank you!